# Find div element on page with two classes, locate its image child and change source

Tags: jquery, html, image, replace

```
<div id="adminOptionsBox" style="z-index: 200; top: 26px;" class="options-box toggleable">
    <img src="images/menu_pointer.png" alt="menu_pointer">
</div>
```

I need to find in this html file div element with two classes: `options-box` and `toggleable` . within it find FIRST image element and change it's source from `images/menu_pointer.png` to `images/menu_pointer2.png`

i have this so far:

```
$('div.options-box.toggleable img').first().attr('src', 'images/menu_pointer2.png');
```

It should be working, but for some reason it is not passing.

Comment: Where did you placed your JS code, maybe it was not executed?

Answer (score 0):

your actual JQuery code works. Have a look at this example:

```
$('div.options-box.toggleable img').first().attr('src', 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B6UEg/

Why do you think it's not working? Maybe the source of your image is not available?

Best